# VueJS handling dynamic input

Tags: vue.js

I have an `vs-input` with `:id=info.tag`. How can I change the input value based on the `:id` tag? Data is dynamic

```html
<template>
  <vs-row vs-type="flex" vs-justify="space-around">
    <div v-for="info in information" :key="info.id">
      <vs-col vs-type="flex" vs-justify="center" vs-align="center" vs-w="3">
        <vx-card :title="info.user_1" :subtitle="info.desc">
          <div slot="footer">
            <vs-row vs-justify="center">
              <vx-input-group class="mb-base">
                <vs-input :id="info.tag" placeholder="Data Output" readonly />
                <br>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <vs-button color="primary" @click="grabData($event, generator.tag)">Grab data</vs-button>
                </div>
              </vx-input-group>
            </vs-row>
          </div>
        </vx-card>
      </vs-col>
    </div>
  </vs-row>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                information: null
            }
        },
        created () {
            this.$store.dispatch('user/getInformation').then(this.$$nextTick).then(() => {
                this.information = this.$store.state.user.information
            })
        },
        methods: {
            grabData(data, tag) {
                this.$store.dispatch('user/grabData', {tag})
                .then(res => { 
                    //Nice! Set input value based on the tag
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    //hmm
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please add your current code and clarify what u intend to do.

Comment: @tuhin47 Updated

Answer (score 0):

So given `vs-input` I assume you are using VueSax.

It has v-model property which will line up to the value.

add `v-model` to `vs-input`

```js
<vs-input :id="info.tag" v-model="infoInput" placeholder="Data Output" readonly/>
```

make sure to include property into data

```js
data() {
    return {
        information: null,
        infoInput: '',
    }
},
```

then when you have an event just change the value.

```js
this.infoInput = "new value"
```

This will update the value in `vs-input`

More info can be found [v-model api](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model)

Comment: Yeah, that would be perfect, but it changes data for all of the others as well then, but I would like to keep it to exactly that card where button was pressed.

Comment: didn't see the for loop. one way to go about it would be arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that each item in `information` has a field named `value`

Then you can just change `vs-input` to this

If you don't have a field name `value` you can add it

```
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch('user/getInformation').then(this.$$nextTick).then(() => {
    this.information = this.$store.state.user.information.map(item => Object.assign({value:''}, item))
  })
}
```